# Receiving a wrong reset password link in Laravel 5.5

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.4, laravel-5.5

I'am using php artisan make:auth in my project, everything work perfectly except the sent link to reset passwords.
The link didn't contain the correct url, the project name is missed.
This is the link sent before I proceed to the notification solution:
http://localhost/password/reset/05929a8e465ddfa123a4c068da455cf63c3b9b90ec500a0e1045f092bbd0d97a
I have create this Method in my User class :

```
public function sendPasswordResetNotification($token) {
    $this->notify(new ResetPasswordNotification($token));
}
```

and then I have created a notification class that contain toMail method to override the existing one in \vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Auth\Notifications\ResetPassword.php:

```
class ResetPasswordNotification extends Notification {
use Queueable;
...
...
    public function toMail($notifiable) {
    return (new MailMessage)
        ->line('You are receiving this email because we received a password reset request for your account.')
        ->action('Reset Password', route('password.reset', $this->token))
        ->line('If you did not request a password reset, no further action is required.');
}
```

The link I got now worked as expected, and this is the sent link:
http://localhost/myproject/public/password/reset/435e453cfa30c968c96ded21c964d70e21459d6ae6ffae8f4972c229773e8a6a. but, I don't know if I change toMail method in ResetPassword.php directly instead of doing it by notification will cause any problems in Production or something else, I will change only ->action part.

Thank's a lot.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In Laravel 5.5, the built in notification builds the url with this code:

```
url(config('app.url').route('password.reset', $this->token, false)))
```

The value of `config('app.url')` can be changed by setting the `APP_URL` variable in your `.env` file. If you set the `APP_URL` value, you do not need to go through the trouble of overriding the built in functionality.

```
APP_URL=http://localhost/myproject/public
```

Comment: I have changed APP_URL link, and It had not worked , that's why I have proceed to this solution. I don't know If I should make some commands after editing APP_URL string ?

Comment: @RachidAzzanati Make sure your config is not cached. `php artisan config:clear` I just ran a test, and changing the `APP_URL` in the `.env` file worked to change the notification url.

Answer (score 0):

In `config/app.php`

Change

```
'url' => env('APP_URL', 'http://localhost'),
```

To:

```
'url' => env('APP_URL', 'http://wwww.yourwebsite.com'),
```